# How do I use a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 to call a external XML source?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am attempting to retrieve currency exchange rates from http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.xml using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2014. The result is in XML. So I created the following stored procedure:

```
--DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CallWebService]
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_CallWebService]
AS
    DECLARE @obj INT
    DECLARE @sURL VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @response varchar(max)

    SET @sURL = 'http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.xml'

    EXEC sys.sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @obj OUT
    EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @obj, 'Open', NULL, 'GET', @sURL, FALSE
    EXEC sys.sp_OAMethod @obj, 'send'
    EXEC sys.sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT

    SELECT @response [response]
    EXEC sys.sp_OADestroy @obj
RETURN
```

and when I run this stored procedure, I get `NULL` in return instead of the XML.

What do I need to change in my stored procedure to get an XML response from that site mentioned above?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30609262/how-do-i-use-a-sp-in-sql-server-2014-to-call-a-external-xml-source

Answer (score 2):

EXEC sys.sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText', @response OUT

sometimes doesn't return the output parameter.  Particularly if the response XML is longer than your @response variable.

Try:

declare  @result table(data text)

INSERT into @result (Data) exec sp_OAGetProperty @obj, 'responseText'

select * from @result

Comment: Did not see this pattern explained anywhere else, but worked like a charm, at least for SqlServer 2014. I recommend using 'nvarchar(max)' instead of 'text'.

Comment: @mdisibio `nvarchar(max)` can only contain 4000 characters, `table(data text)` made the trick, thank you @Bruce

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani I agree. Varchar and nvarchar limits can be a challenge. I made that comment based on Microsoft's ongoing warning since SqlServer 2008: _"ntext, text, and image data types will be removed ... Avoid using these data types ... Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead."_ [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017](BOL). I think the idea is that if you call an external xml source, it would be a reasonable sized message (REST maybe). Xml as a parameter type still supports large documents.

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani. But re-reading your specific issue, you were already using `varchar(max)`, so recommending `nvarchar(max)` is sensless...even less capacity. Sorry for the confusion. Was raising the flag about a data type that might get deprecated, as well as the fact that Sql Server - when _not_ using the `xml` data type, usually handles xml as `nvarchar`.

Comment: @mdisibio this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22067593/calling-an-api-from-sql-server-stored-procedure has more than 42k viewes. as you can see on the first response, on line 2 they use `Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);` which was the maximum allowed. try to swap it with `Declare @ResponseText as varchar(MAX);` or `Declare @ResponseText as nvarchar(MAX);` and you will see it epically fail because `Varchar(MAX);` and `Narchar(MAX);` can only store till 4000 characters! Yes, you hear it well!

Comment: @Bruce reply was mind blowing for me! thanks to his hint on the same page I linked you above I added my reply and as you can see I'm using `Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))` on line 3. And now I can retrieve till **2 GB** and **65,535 characters**. Isn't that fun! XML and JSON. I hope this will help many persons